# Rollup generates empty bundle

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rollup

I would like to bundle a .js file with rollup that has only a class definition in it. But rollup creates only an empty bundle-file. This changes when I add some code outside the class Definition. 
This creates an empty bundle:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement{
    constructor() {...}
    ...
}
```

And this creates a filled bundle:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement{
    constructor() {...}
    ...
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

But I don't want to have the ...define() in that file.
Is there a way to convice rollup.js to just bundle the class-definition?

Comment: make sure you export your component

Answer (score 12):

Old topic but can be useful for those who are researching:
for me it worked:

change the file **tsconfig.json**

```json
  "emitDeclarationOnly": false,
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a module that defines a class in its local scope but doesn't do anything with it - neither export it nor use it to perform a side effect like passing it to `define`. It's dead code - and that will be stripped by rollup. You'll likely want to use

```
export default class MyElement extends HTMLElement { /*
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
    constructor() { … }
    …
}
```

which can be bundled to something that still exports the class so that it is usable elsewhere.

Comment: just adding 'export default' doesn't Change anything unfortunatly. I would like to use that class from inside a script tag in an imported html.file

Comment: Then you need to specify in your rollup config that you want this module as the entry, and export it to the global scope.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: @JustinThomas Use [umd/iife output format](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputformat) and specify the [output name](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputname)